# Can you specify type argument for None or tell compiler that it's an Option[String]?

Tags: scala, types

I wonder if I can write something like this in my code:

```
None[String]
```

Answer (score 60):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned the existence of `Option.empty`:

```
scala> Option.empty[String]
res0: Option[String] = None
```

Note that in many cases simply using `None` where an `Option[String]` is expected will work fine. 
Or in other words, (as shown by Aleksey Izmailov), the following is corrrect:

```
def f(o: Option[String]) = ...; f(None)
```

This is because `None` extends `Option[Nothing]`, so by virtue of `Option` being covariant (and `Nothing` being a sub-type of every other type), `None` is always a compatible with `Option[T]` for any `T`.

This is also why type ascription is also a fine alternative (for the cases where you do need to be explicit on the type of options, by example if it is needed to drive type inference):

```
scala> None: Option[String]
res0: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Yes `Option.empty[Type]` is the best practice. Similarly for empty lists and such one should do `List.empty[Type]`

Comment: @samthebest Are there reasons why `Option.empty` is better than explicit type annotation? Just curious

Comment: @acjay well explicit type annotation is very nice too. My argument would be that the code is then consistent with the collections hierarchy meaning the code to create an empty list is exactly the same as creating an empty option.  This will make type refactors easier, and/or make it easier to do some advanced scala with disjunction types or duck typing. If you ask this as a separate question I'll give some examples :)

Comment: @samthebest Okay, asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806407/when-should-empty-be-used-versus-the-singleton-empty-instance

Answer (score 9):

If you want to specify the type of `Option` you could use:

> None:Option[String]

The colon is an explicit type annotation.

Answer (score 8):

`Option` is a parameterized type and is defined as such:

```
... sealed abstract class Option[+A] ...
```

it's being extended by 2 other classes:

```
final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A]
```

and

```
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

While `Some` can take any type of an argument, `None` is a special instance/singleton of an `Option` parameterized with `Nothing`. Furthermore `Option` is covariant in its type argument `[+A]` which means that `Option[Nothing]` can be used anywhere where `Option` with any other argument type is expected, since `Nothing` extends all types in Scala. So there is no need to create any other values to represent a `Nothing` value, a singleton `None` will be sufficient for all cases.

In terms of extensibility `Option` is a sealed abstract class, so you can't extend it. You can't extend its subclasses `Some` and `None` since they are case classes.

Usually you don't even need to try to write something like `None[String]` because more specific `Option` type is defined somewhere in the context. For example, as a function argument:

```
def f(o: Option[String]) = ...; f(None)
```

or as a refinement:

```
val o: Option[String] = None
```

Moreover, you really don't care what type an Option was if it's a `Nothing` value, you can't get anything out of it anyway, it's like a `null` in Java but with Monadic behavior.

It's been mentioned that you can do something similar in scalaz: `none[String]`. This is just a syntax sugar, albeit very convenient, to reduce verbosity in some cases where types have to be annotated. It's defined as such:

```
final def none[A]: Option[A] = None
```

Comment: @Aleksey Izmailov: Your `none` method already exists in the standard library: `Option.empty`.

Comment: it's not my method, I copied `none` from scalaz ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can with scalaz:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

none[String]  // res0: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: I know you write , my point is whether can i specify type as None Like: val a : None[String] =