# Fold collection with None as start value

Tags: scala, collections, fold, scala-option

I want to fold a collection or Y's and return an Option[X].  I want to start with None.  Like this...

```
def f(optX: Option[X], y: Y): Option[X]
val optX = collectionOfY.fold(None) { case (prev, y) => f(prev,y) }
```

adding unneeded types to make it clearer

```
val optX: Option[X] = collectionOfY.fold(None) { case (prev: Option[X], y: Y) => f(prev,y) }
```

However, the compiler can not figure out the type properly and I have to write it like this

```
val xx: Option[X] = None
val optX = collectionOfY.fold(xx) { case (prev, y) => f(prev,y) }
```

What is the magic Scala syntax to write this?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the magic Scala syntax to write this"?

Comment: Just looking for a way to avoid the val xx: Option[X] = None.  Option[T].empty is the answer I was looking for

Comment: You could use `reduce` instead of `fold`, then you wouldn't have to provide a starting value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `foldLeft` and any of the following

`... foldLeft(Option.empty[X]) ...` or `... foldLeft(None: Option[X]) ...` or `... foldLeft[Option[X]](None) ...`

After all, `fold` just calls `foldLeft`.  You only really want to use `fold` when your `A1` really is a super-type of `A`, if that really is the case then you can use `fold` as above and the compiler will know the type correctly.

For example, `Option[List[Int]] <: Option[Seq[Int]]` by covariance so we don't get an `Any` here:

```
List(Some(List(1,2,3))).fold[Option[Seq[Int]]](None)((_, _) => Some(Seq(1)))

> res2: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1))
```

Finally, if you do indeed know `Option[X]` will be a super-type of `Y` then say this explicitly in the type declaration of `Y` - i.e. `Y <: Option[X]`, then you can use `fold` with the solutions given above.

See [When should .empty be used versus the singleton empty instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806407/when-should-empty-be-used-versus-the-singleton-empty-instance) for a related discussion.

Comment: Thank you.  That's interesting, I didn't realize the rules would be different for foldLeft and fold.  However, for my problem, Option.empty[T] does the trick nicely

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments above, the preferred solution is change the first parameter passed to `Option.fold` to avoid the use of `None` and use `Option.empty[X]` instead.

```
val optX = collectionOfY.fold(Option.empty[X]) { case (prev, y) => f(prev,y) }
```

The Scala compiler accepts this without complaint.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is logical, because fold is defined as

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

that means the starting parameter is a supertype of `A`, but `None` is's a supertype of `Option[T]`. If you specify the type directly (like in your second example) then the compiler has enough information to figure out the return type of fold.

One possible workaround is to specify the result of interaction of head of your collection with `None` as a starting point, and fold it with the rest of the collection (adding a check for `Nil`):

```
val optX = collectionOfY.match {
  case Nil => None
  case x:xs => xs.fold(f(None,x)) {case (prev,y) => f(prev,y) }
}
```